# Kendo Grid - accessing and manipulating the item object

Tags: kendo-grid

Well I've gotten exactly zero responses to my half-dozen Angular-Kendo-UI grid questions, so I'm gonna cross my finger and hope my problems can be solved more generally. Maybe there's an easier way of manipulating the grid items.

I want to access the objects that contain my data (order items, in this case).

My grid's rows have a checkbox for selecting orders. When the user selects an order, I want to retrieve and manipulate that object.

```
// dataSource
vm.masterGrid.dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport:{
        read: function(options) {
             return vm.getOrders(options);
        }
    },
    pageSize: 5,
    serverPaging: true,
});

//options
vm.masterGrid.gridOptions = {
    columns: [
        { title: "Buyer", field: "BuyerName" },
        { 
            title:  "Select", 
            template: "<input " + 
                        type='checkbox'  " + 
                        class='checkbox'  " + 
                        ng-disabled='#=!HasValidCustomsInfo#'  " + 
                        ng-click='ordersVm.selectForPackaging(Id)'  " + 
                        ng-model='Id'/>"
         }
    ]
};
```

The view:

```
        <div 
             kendo-grid 
             k-height="'400px'" 
             k-data-source="ordersVm.masterGrid.dataSource" 
             k-options="ordersVm.masterGrid.gridOptions">
        </div>
```

Here's where I'm trying to get the object so I can do stuff with it:

```
// checkbox-click on row
vm.selectForPackaging = function (orderId) {
    console.log(orderId); // returns true (useless)
    console.log(vm.getOrderItemById(99)); // returns [init: {my actual object which I can't access}]
};
```

(My get-order-item-by-id helper function:)

```
    vm.getOrderItemById = function (orderId) {
        var matches = $filter('filter')( vm.masterGrid.dataSource.data(), function(gridItem, index) {
            return gridItem.Id == orderId;
        });
    };
```

What I get back in vm.selectForPackaging actually contains my data  but it isn't usable!

It looks like this in the console:

```
v init {_events: Object, _handlers: Object, OrderLines: init[1], Store: init, Id: 99…}
    AddressIsValid:true
    BuyerEmail:"lance.slack@gmail.com"
    etc...
```

which would be fine, but I can't get it the data!

Calling **vm.getOrderItemById(99).init**  should return my actual object. Instead it returns a function:

```
function (e){var t,n,i=this,r=function(){return i};we.fn.init.call(this),this._handlers={};for(n in e)t=e[n],"object"==typeof t&&t&&!t.getTime&&"_"!=n.charAt(0)&&(t=i.wrap(t,n,r)),i[n]=t;i.uid=_e.guid…
```

If I call that function: **vm.getOrderItemById(99).init()** I get **undefined**.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dataItem` method to get the current row information

```
// checkbox-click on row
vm.selectForPackaging = function () {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr"),
    var grid = $(vm.masterGrid).data("kendoGrid"),
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);
    console.log(dataItem);
};
```

Please refer the live example [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/@amaldevv/UCoNA)